# How do i randomise video in a html for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hello everyone i am trying to make a chrome extension but i am not really sure what to do! This is my code ( it is quite long) i am trying to do a randomisation when you click the icon and have video in it but i cant understand it as i have looked it up but is quite a specific question!

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: opx;
font-family: Comic Sans MS;
font-size: 13px;
}

</style>
</head>
</body>

<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try again</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

if x = 1) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x = 2) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x = 3) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 3.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x = 4) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 4.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x = 5) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 5.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x = 6) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 6.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any replys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick list of what's wrong with your code :

- The syntax of your `if` is incorrect, you're omitting the opening parenthesis.
- You are not comparing values in your if conditions, you are assigning a value. You should use `==` instead of `=`.
- The block of conditions is not included in the function body, so it will be executed only once, not each time the function is called.
- The content of your if is just plain HTML, instead of javascript code to modify the inner HTML of `<p id="demo"></p>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! so how would i change the if syntax. Also i'm not sure what you mean by you'r 3rd bullet point!